# bash - llamar a script remoto para instalar app de manera local

Tags: bash, script, curl, pipe, wget

Estoy tratando de crear un script el cual aloje en un Apache. el contenido de dicho script es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Dependencias
declare -a dependencias=( "unzip" "wget" "curl" "mkdir" "tree" )

echo "Content-Type: application/x-sh"
echo ""

echo "Ruta de Instalacion: "
echo ""
PATH_ROOT=$1

if [ -z "$PATH_ROOT" ]; then
      echo "No se entrego path para instalacion "
      exit;
else
      
      for i in "${dependencias[@]}"; do
          command -V $i
          if [ $? = 1 ]; then
              exit;
          fi
      done
    
fi
```

Para llamar a este script de manera remota ejecuto este curl:

> curl -sSL http://algun.dominio.com/setup/install.sh | bash -s -- opt

La salida de dicho script es la siguiente:

> bash: line 1: Ruta: command not found
>
> bash: line 3: No: command not found

En pocas palabras no estoy logrando que se ejecute mi bash remoto de manera local.

Este tipo de instalación ya la he visto en otro ejemplos, creo que la llamada curl esta bien, pero si alguien podría ayudarme con el código, lo agradecería mucho.

Si necesitan más info solo pregunten. Gracias.

Comment: Tú código se ve bien. Prueba descargando el archivo ".sh" remoto en tu maquina local, y luego ejecútalo con bash y di qué sucede después.

Comment: lo descarge con un wget, y lo que obtengo del sh es el siguiente conteniedo: "Ruta de Instalacion:
No se entrego path para instalacion". Esta descargando lo que imprimo de mi sh. estaba pensando que tal vez estaba malo mi VHost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo resolví. El problema es como declare el VirtualHost en apache,. No debe ser declarado como un CGI si no que como un archivo común, por lo menos de esa manera funciona.

Este es el VirtualHost original

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
      ScriptAlias /setup/ /opt/scripts/install/
      DocumentRoot /opt/scripts/install
      ServerName algun.dominio.com

      <Directory "/opt/scripts/install">
           Options +ExecCGI
           AddHandler cgi-script .py .sh
           Order deny,allow
           Deny from all
           Allow from X.X.X.X
           Allow from X.X.X.X   

      </Directory>
      ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_install.log
      TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_install.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Y este es como quedo:

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
    Alias /setup/ /opt/scripts/install/
    DocumentRoot /opt/scripts/install
    ServerName algun.dominio.com
    <Directory "/opt/scripts/install">
              Order deny,allow
              Deny from all
              Allow from X.X.X.X
              Allow from X.X.X.X
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_install.log
    TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_install.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Debe quedar como texto plano y no CGI, para que el curl lo descarge y por medio del | (pipe) bash lo pueda interpretar, ese era el problema.

Gracias por la ayuda.